# How to reset identifier​For​Vendor in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm doing some testing with an SDK that involves identifier​For​Vendor (IDFV).  Currently, my IDFV is constant, and because I'm running the app on an iPhone via Xcode (not downloading the app from the App Store), I cannot reset my IDFV by uninstalling all apps from a given vendor.

How do I reset my IDFV?

Comment: What is "IDFV"?

Comment: @rmaddy identifierForVendor - see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out you can reset IDFV for Xcode emulator device by navigating to simulator, clicking "Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... > Reset".